# Want to list all the jobs that were executed manually in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-job

How can I get a list of all the jobs that were executed manually last week?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this information from msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory table.
Visit [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to refer more about it.

Here is a sample. Hope to help, my friend.

```
SELECT sj.name,
       sjh.step_name,
       sjh.step_id,
       sjh.run_status,
       STUFF(STUFF(CAST(sjh.run_date as nvarchar(10)),5,0,'.'),8,0,'.') as HistRunDate,
       STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(sjh.run_time as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as HistRunTime,
       STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(sjh.run_duration as varchar(8)), 8), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') as HistRunDuration
       ,sjh.run_status AS JobStatus
FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs           AS sj
       join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS sjh 
            on sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
WHERE  1=1

AND ((sjh.run_date = 20190401 and sjh.run_time > 200000) 
or (sjh.run_date = 20190409 and sjh.run_time < 100000))

ORDER BY
       sjh.run_date,
       sjh.run_time
```

Answer (score 0):

OP asked how to tell all jobs executed *manually*.  To do so, Tomato''s query should include a join to msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity referencing the "run_requested_source" column.

From Microsoft.

run_requested_source (Who requested the job to run)

```
1 = SOURCE_SCHEDULER
2 = SOURCE_ALERTER
3 = SOURCE_BOOT
4 = SOURCE_USER
6 = SOURCE_ON_IDLE_SCHEDULE

    SELECT sj.name,
       sjh.step_name,
       sjh.step_id,
       sjh.run_status,
       STUFF(STUFF(CAST(sjh.run_date as nvarchar(10)),5,0,'.'),8,0,'.') as HistRunDate,
       STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(sjh.run_time as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') as HistRunTime,
       STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(sjh.run_duration as varchar(8)), 8), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') as HistRunDuration
       ,sjh.run_status AS JobStatus

FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs           AS sj
       join msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS sjh on sjh.job_id = sj.job_id
       join msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity AS sa on sj.job_id = sa.job_id
WHERE
    (
        ((sjh.run_date = 20190401 and sjh.run_time > 200000) 
        or (sjh.run_date = 20190409 and sjh.run_time < 100000))
    )
    and sa.run_requested_source = 4

ORDER BY
       sjh.run_date,
       sjh.run_time
```